# Attribute with this code is not super in row(s) - Confirmed global setting and assigned to attribute set

Tags: attribute-set, sku-length

I created the parent (super) and used the 'create configuration' to choose the attribute and create the children.
My skus are long, could this be causing the problem (i.e. 083-000022-Chartreuse Lime Alternating w Orange Accent - 311SW)